# yum hangs on installing a specific package

Tags: yum

tried to install squid with command

```
yum install squid
```

and it consistently hangs on

```
Running Transaction
 Installing: squid                        #####################     [1/1]
```

Had no problems with hundreds of other packages. Does anyone have an idea on what could be the problem?

**edit**: tried both: yum clean all + changing mirror, and rebuild rpm, doesn't help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if you have a corrupted package.  I suggest running *yum clean all* and start again.  You probably will get a different mirror and a fresh download.

Answer (score 2):

I would try Keith's suggestion of "yum clean all" first.  If that doesn't work, I have encountered a situation like this when there is actually an issue with the RPM database.

You can try to rebuild the RPM database by doing:

> sudo rm -f /var/lib/rpm/__db.* (you could move them to a temporary directory to be cautious)
>
> sudo /bin/rpm --rebuilddb

After that completes, try the "yum install squid" again.